# Can a wine program access files outside of the virtual C: drive?

Tags: wine

I have to run a program that I don't really trust and I afraid that it may mess up my computer.
It is a Windows program so I have to run it in Wine, but I don't want it to access anything outside the virtual C drive.
Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't trust it, don't run it. Wine is not particularly well secured against this type of attack - simply because it's not meant to be a sandbox. In short, you can assume that a program has the same access as your user.

A good alternative is a seperate, virtual machine. VM environments *are* to a certain degree made with such risks in mind.